# CSS Effect add as Active Effect

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="mon-img hovicon effect-1 sub-a mon-active">
    <img class="icon-active" src="http://placehold.it/125X125&text=Blood" width="100px" data-info="blood" />
</div>
```

the `mon-active` add the hover effect I use to the div when hovered. However, when `mon-active` is added to make to the div and hovered again, it was somehow bouncing, I wanted to move that thing away, but I have been gone through many css changes and yet I cannot make it like as hovered.

Here is my [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pvt62dv/)

What I want is to make it just like the hovered and the placement should still be the same.

I don't know how to make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant comment so I'm just gonna post your recent problem with the moving circles

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pvt62dv/4/)

Added some padding to your css to make the circle stable.
CSS:

```
.mon-img {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:7px; /* added to your code */
}

.hovicon.effect-1.sub-a:hover {
    background: rgba(72, 195, 245, 1);
    color: #41ab6b;
    padding: 7px; /* added to your code */
}

.mon-active:hover  {
    box-shadow: initial;
    box-sizing: initial;
    background: #009ddb;
    padding: 7px; /* added to your code */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `.mon-active:hover  {padding: 0px;}`, check it using use `padding: 7px;`, placement problem will solve, js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/wpnimitz/8pvt62dv/.

Comment: it works, however, the items (before and/or after) was moving 7px, i have been adjusting this for 2 days now, I haven't found the fix. I just wanted it to be steady.

Comment: Sorry to say, now I am little bit confused. Now what's wrong with it?

Comment: When you hover on the second or third.. They wont move but wikk have the circle..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin of 7px on hover:-

```
.mon-active:hover  {
    box-shadow: initial;
    box-sizing: initial;
    background: #009ddb;
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pvt62dv/1/)

Comment: it works, however, the items (before and/or after) was moving 7px, i have been adjusting this for 2 days now, I haven't found the fix. I just wanted it to be steady.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the hover animation from the active div to prevent displaying same animation over and over.